# How to replace dataframe column with separate dict values - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary-comprehension

My `user_artist_plays` dataframe below shows a user column, but for statistical computation I must replace these mixed characters with `int` only IDs.

```
    users                                       artist  plays
0   00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    sting   12763
1   00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    stars   8192
2   fffe8c7f952d9b960a56ed4dcb40a415d924b224    cher    117
3   fffe8c7f952d9b960a56ed4dcb40a415d924b224    queen   117
```

The above shows multiple entries for only two users, which is ok if I can have the column match any entry with an existing key in the separate dictionary:

```
users = user_artist_plays['users'].unique()
user_dict = {ni: indi for indi, ni in enumerate(set(users))}
user_dict

{'068156fafd9c4237c174c648d3d484cbf509cb75': 0,
 '6deecfbc46a81e4faf398b2afd991be05ab78f10': 74205,
 '1e23333ff4f637420a8a38d467ccecfda064afb9': 1,
 '0b282cafc949efe4163b7946b7104957a18cf010': 2,
 'd1867cbda35e0d48e9a8390d9f5e079c9d99ea96': 3}
```

Here's my attempt at switching out for `int` values:

```
for k, v in user_dict.items():
        if user_artist_plays['users'].any(k):
            user_artist_plays['users'].replace(v)
```

It's retaining the original values of the `users` column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
user_artist_plays['users'] = user_artist_plays['users'].map(user_dict)
```

Or [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
user_artist_plays['users'] = pd.factorize(user_artist_plays['users'])[0]
```